# How can I extend IEnumerable<T> to load my collection from a web service?

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable, ienumerator

I've been trying to puzzle out how I could implement `Enumerable<T>`/`IEnumerator<T>` to satisfy the following:

1. I call a web service to create a query
2. I poll the web service to find out when it is ready to return results
3. Once the web service is ready to return results, I call a method (e.g. `GetNext(n)`) to get *n* items from it
4. Once `GetNext(n)` returns less than *n* results I have retrieved all of my items.

I'm having some difficulty trying to figure out how I could make an IEnumerable handle all of the heavy lifting from me and the MSDN IEnumerable documentation has not helped.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
public class MyEnumerable : IEnumerable
{
    private MyWebService _service;
    private int _queryID;

    public MyEnumerable(MyWebService service, int queryID)
    {
        _service = service;
        _queryID = queryID;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new MyEnumerator(_service, _query);
    }
}

public class MyEnumerator : IEnumerator
{
    private List<QueryResult> _items;  //want to load my items from WebService into this
    private MyWebService _service;
    private int _queryID;
    private int _index = 0;

    private MyEnumerator(MyWebService service, int queryID)
    {
        _service = service;
        _queryID = queryID;
    }

    public object Current
    {
        //what goes here? 
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        //what goes here? would I call the web service here?
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        _index = 0;
    }

}
```

Hopefully this makes a bit more sense. Let's assume I can call a method on my webservice called GetNext(n).

Comment: You shouldn't be polling a web service to find out when it has results, you should just be notified through a callback of some sort.

Comment: lazyberezovsky - I've tried implementing IEnumerable and IEnumerator and using my custom Enumerator to perform the web service logic but I haven't been able to figure out how to correctly write the enumerator (and my code doesn't compile).

Comment: @MailmanOdd Then show us what you've tried, or a simplified version that can demonstrate the problem, and explain, specifically, what problems you are having.

Comment: @MailmanOdd show us your code and what exception do you get

Comment: For a stream of data like this, I think I'd look into Rx's IObservables. Enumerables are much closer to arrays, designed around data storage, whereas Observables are based around data that may be coming in any time.

Comment: @Magus The choice between the two is all about whether the caller should have a synchronous vs asynchronous interface.  An `IEnumerable` can be appropriate if the caller is willing to just block until there is a result.

Comment: And since he mentioned polling, he wants asynchronous.

Comment: Well, I want to abstract the asynchronous nature away from the consumer of the Enumerable object, so I do actually want to block while getting next results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than explicitly implementing the interface, unless you have a reason not to, you should generally use an iterator block to create such sequences.  It will take care of the boilerplate code, just leaving you with the interesting implementation.  A problem like this will generally look something along these lines:

```
//you can make this private if you want
public static IEnumerable<IList<Foo>> GetPages(int pageSize)
{
    IList<Foo> nextGroup = ExecuteQuery();
    while (nextGroup.Count == pageSize)
    {
        yield return nextGroup;
        nextGroup = ExecuteQuery();
    }
    if (nextGroup.Any())
        yield return nextGroup;
}
```

You can then use `SelectMany` to flatten out the list of groups into a list of the individual items:

```
public static IEnumerable<Foo> GetItems(int pageSize)
{
    return GetPages(pageSize).SelectMany(x => x);
}
```

Comment: Hm, I like this idea. It makes this much simpler. I think I will implement it this way and add it to my WebService consumer class. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use Rx Reactive Extensions, and the Buffer extension method. (Meaning, IObservable rather than IEnumberable). Seems to match your use case perfectly!